# What's the difference between ' * ' and ' ? '?

Tags: cron, node-schedule

The title already explains what my problem is...

I tried some Cron generators online and they either use '*' or '?' for an expressions to be used with 'node-schedule'.

I'm trying to run a CronJob at 2am everyday, so `0 0 2 ? * *` and `0 0 2 * * *` both mean the same thing?

Would `0 0 2 ? ? ?` also have the same meaning as the two examples above?

I am really confused and I'd appreciate some clarification on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, no, ? is allowed only for day in week and day in month. (As second and fourth character in * ? * ? * *)

For example, you want to run task every 10th in month, but don't care which day it is...

More on http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html

Comment: I will read more into that.  Thanks for providing the link for that tutorial!